# How to change transparent_hugepage to "never" in google cloud ubuntu vm?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have setup a vm with mongodb in Google Cloud Engine and Mongodb is madly complaining about /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled and /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag being set to always. 
How can I set those to never in a way that the configuration is not overwritten by package upgrades? 
I tried "sim" suggestion 2 from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages which did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out! 
hugeadm --thp-never
does the trick. No idea if it will be overwritten by package upgrades xP~

Comment: Please, consider elaborating further your answer for future users looking for this and flagging your own answer as a valid answer for the question.